# How to find the period of motion in MATLAB?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm analysing the motion of a planet in a central force field by solving two second order differential equations that describe the motion in the $x$ and $y$ directions using the 4th order Runge-Kutta  method.

When I plot the solution, I get the following graph:

[image]

The graph is a plot of y - displacement against x - displacement. It's the orbit of a particular planet. I would like to find the period of motion of the planet from the graph. How can one do this in MATLAB?

Comment: What if you plot x or y against time?

Comment: Works great! Thank you.

Comment: @fibonatic Just a comment left passing by: if you're not sure about period of motion even after taking a look at $y$ vs $t$ plot, use techniques like Discrete Fourier Transforms. There's a nice example in MATLAB help on using DFT for revealing periodicity of sun activity -- it'll give you a grasp of how you might use this in more complicated case.